# Powershell with Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

What I need to do is to extract the data in the excel row and output them into different rows on Excel. After that, I will need to use the extracted data and perform certain conditions on the extracted data.

This is my current script:

1. To open excel and apply the formulas

> ```
> $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
> $filepath = 'D:\testexcel.xlsx'
> $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("$filepath")
> $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
>
> $excel.Visible = $true
>
> $rows = $worksheet.range("A1").currentregion.rows.count 
> $worksheet.range("S1:S$rows").formula = $worksheet.range("S1").formula
> ```

2. Function to find the row, apply the formula and output it

> ```
> function test123(){
>     param([string]$test123)
>
>     $sourcefile = "D:\testexcel.xlsx"
>     $sheetname = "abc"
>
>     $excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
>     $excel.Visible = $true
>     $excelworkbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($sourcefile, 2, $true) 
>     $excelworksheet = $excelworkbook.worksheets.item($sheetname)
>
>     $row = 1
>     $column = 1
>     $found = $false
>     while(($excelworksheet.cells.item($row, $column).value() -ne $null) -and($found -eq $false)){ 
>         if(($excelworksheet.cells.item($row, $column).value()).toupper() -eq $test123.ToUpper()){
>             write-host $excelworksheet.cells.item($row, $column).value() $excelworksheet.cells.item($row, $column+1).value(), 
>             $excelworksheet.cells.item($row, $column +2).value() $found = $true
>             }
>         $row += 1
>     }
>
>     #close workbook
>     $excelworkbook.close()
>     $excel.quit()
> }
> test123 -test123 "Test123"
> ```

Please guide me and tell me if this is the right way to do it... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look into the ImportExcel module by Douge Finke. This module has the capability to do what you need.

Get it from PowerShell gallery: `Install-Module -Name ImportExcel`

Github link: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

you can then do `Get-Help Import-Excel -Examples` which has pretty good examples.